# how to make cardview a parent layout with scrollable content

Tags: java, android

i am working on some application but want to make card view widget a parent layout, problem is my content is not vertically scrollable inside the cardview widget,how can i solve it,thank you.
here is my code;

```
tools:context="com.example.hacker.guidekyu.Home">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:text="   WELCOME TO KYU"
        />
    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/bckgrndViewFlipper1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView8"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/one" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/two" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/three" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/two" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bckgrndImageView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/one" />


    </ViewFlipper>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:background="#58a3c1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Administration"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Administration"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:background="#58a3c1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:background="#58a3c1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:background="#58a3c1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff0"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:background="#58a3c1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Administration"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try putting everything inside the cardview inside a scrollview. That should allow scrolling, though since the cardview is wrap_content, it will be of the exact same size as the inner part. Change it to something fixed-> smaller in size than the inner content to see scroll happening

Comment: alright thanks let me do that

Answer (score 0):

put everything inside the cardview inside a scrollview.

That should allow scrolling.

Change the cardview parameters from wrap_content to something fixed-> smaller in size than the inner content to see scroll happening